# Word VBA Text then table then text then table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Hello I am trying to basically create a word document from scratch using excel vba with the word objects. The original document is 2 pages long. On the first page it has text, then table, then text, then another table. On the second page there is just text.

I have figured out part of it so far, however I have no idea how to move the cursor to add the new table. I am new to VBA

```
Sub CreateBasicWordReport()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim objRange
    Dim objDoc
    Dim Cell
    Dim NewRange

    Set wdApp = New Word.Application


    With wdApp
         .Visible = True
         .Activate

         .Documents.Add

                With .Selection
                     .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                     .BoldRun
                     .Font.Size = 11
                     .TypeText "Letter to Proceed with Transfer"
                     .TypeParagraph
                     .Font.Size = 11
                     .TypeText "Determination of Transfer Value and Request for Transfer"
                     .TypeParagraph
                     .TypeParagraph
                     .TypeParagraph

                     .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft


                End With



        End With

      Set objRange = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range
      objRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

      wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add objRange, 4, 2

      With wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range

         .Bold = False
         .Text = "Date"

      End With

      With wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range

         .Bold = False
         .Text = "Exportin"

      End With

      With wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(3, 1).Range

         .Bold = False
         .Text = "Importing"

      End With

      With wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(4, 1).Range

         .Bold = False
         .Text = "Re"

      End With

      With wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range

         .Bold = False
         .Text = "Re"

      End With

      With wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range

         .Bold = False
         .Text = "Re"

      End With

      With wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(3, 2).Range

         .Bold = False
         .Text = "Re"

      End With


      With wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(4, 2).Range

         .Bold = False
         .Text = "Re"

      End With


      objRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

      wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter "_____________________________________________________________________________________"
      wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter "Part 1"

      wdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists ("\EndOfDoc")


     ' wdApp.ActiveDocument.
      'Set NewRange = ActiveDocument.Content
      'NewRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd


      'wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add (

      'wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd





      'objRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

      'wdApp.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = "FGHFHDFg"

      'wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add NewRange, 4, 2

      'Set objTable = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tabl
      'objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "WOO"

      'wdApp.Documents.Add.Tables.Add wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range, 5, 4






End Sub
```

First Page

[image: First Page]

Second Page

[image: Second Page]

Comment: Are you just looking for a page break?

Comment: That and also, how do i add text, table then more text the another table. Currently, it adds a table within another table and the cursor is stuck in the first table.

Comment: Are you always referencing table(1)?

Comment: Why are you not using a Word template? If you prefer the masochistic approach, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/44537-run-time-error-5941-requested-member-collection.html. As the code there amply demonstrates, there is no need to 'move the cursor'.

Comment: How would one use a template? how do you even build a word template?

Comment: Also, the template cannot be static there are conditions where it needs to decide to add certain messages of text or not. this will be based on the excel file

Comment: You don't provide enough information. We (and the code) need a way to *identify* where "to move the cursor to add the new table". We don't know what's going on here, beyond the information provided in the question, which is insufficient because there's no *structure*.

Answer (score 0):

Every Word document is based on a template. Every Word document also uses Styles to manage the formatting and layout. This is really, really basic Word stuff. You need to spend some time learning how Word works before rushing off to code anything.

A template is basically a document with all the standard 'boilerplate content' and, depending on your requirements, some variable content, saved as a template (e.g. a .dotx file). Clearly, you already have such a document, but saved as a template. You then create a new document by referencing the template via Documents.Add.

And, if you insert bookmarks wherever your variable inputs might go (before saving), it's a simple matter for your macro to instruct Word what to insert at those bookmarks - all without ever needing to move the cursor or select anything.

Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/44567-text-then-table-then-more-text-table.html

For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184